# Google Analytics not sending hits in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

When i am using `Objective-c` as a coding language google analytics is sending data properly but when it comes to `swift` i am so much messed. It is not sending any hits. Since i am not using `cocoapods` dependency so **I have imported following files:-**

```
GAI.h
GAIDictionaryBuilder.h
GAIEcommerceProduct.h
GAIEcommerceProductAction.h
GAIEcommercePromotion.h
GAIFields.h
GAILogger.h
GAITrackedViewController.h
GAITracker.h
```

**And I am importing following frameworks :-**

```
CoreData.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
libz.dylib
libsqlite3.dylib
libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a
```

**And my code for App-delegate is :-**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
    {
        GAI.sharedInstance().trackUncaughtExceptions = true  //tracking exception

        GAI.sharedInstance().dispatchInterval = 20   //time interval for sending data

        GAI.sharedInstance().trackerWithTrackingId("UA-xxxxxxx-1") //Tracking id

        GAI.sharedInstance().logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.Verbose
            //For getting verbal messages in console
   }
```

My code for screen tracking is :-

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker

            tracker.setValue(kGai, forKey: "Tab4")

            tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build)
```

And log that i am getting in the console is :-

```
2016-07-18 13:57:46:394 App_GA[11685:1073352] Verbose
2016-07-18 13:57:46:395 App_GA[11685:1073352] Debug
2016-07-18 13:57:46:395 App_GA[11685:1073352] Info
2016-07-18 13:57:46:396 App_GA[11685:1073352] Warn
2016-07-18 13:57:46:396 App_GA[11685:1073352] Error
documentPath ::Optional("/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/26EC3AF9-9D88-4D9F-88AC-7CE0F6D0F93D/Documents")
setup ::nil, device::nil
success
```

Please help !

Comment: what the problem u faced

Comment: i am receiving any hits on google analytics

Comment: when u added GA in your project

Comment: on google analytics page it should send the active device, page and events but it is not sending any thing to google analytics. So as a result zero session and zero user is showing on analytics web page.

Comment: where is your screen track and event track functions

Comment: let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().trackerWithTrackingId("UA-XXXX-1)
                
            tracker.setValue(kGai, forKey: "Tab4")
            
            tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build)